# Recursive Sybase Select

Tags: sql, recursion, sybase, recursive-query

I have the users_entities table, it contains the users, their entities and their dependant entities. Like this.

```
|user | entity | dependant entity|
----------------------------------
| 122 | 746414 |      null       |
| 122 | 746410 |     746414      |
| 122 | 746405 |     746414      |
| 333 | 746403 |     746405      |
```

So, with a

```
select entity from users_entities where user = 122
```

I get: 706414, 706410, and 746405.

All of the entities where 122 is in charge, but I also have to show all the entities that depend of those entities. So, I will also have to show 746403 because it depends of 746405.

It's a tree structure

```
74614
  |
746405 
  |
746403
```

I suppose I have to do a recursive select, but I can't get it done. Can it be done with a single select? Or I'll have to do a function or a stored procedure? Thanks.

*Edit*
Oh, I forgot. They can be multiple level of dependants.

Comment: Can you have multiple levels of dependants?

Comment: @sgeddes Yes, I can have multiple levels of dependants. Sorry, I forgot that part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a self-join. But you need to know the maximum number of levels. If the maximum is, say, 5, then you could write a 5-way self-join. When you use outer join predicates, it should be able to handle anything less than that number of levels.
Something like this (I did not test the query but you'll get the idea; this is done for 3 levels maximum but you can extend it):

```
select t1.user as user1, t2.user as user2, t3.user as user3
from
users_entities t1 
left outer join users_entities t2
on t1.entity = t2.entity 
left outer join users_entities t3
on t2.entity = t3.entity 
where t1.user = 122
```